# cocos2d schedule cannot be called

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have two schedule in class @A.

first one:

```
 - (id) init ()
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self ) {

        ....

        [self schedule:@selector(first:) interval:1.0f];
    }
}
```

second:

```
- (void) setSomething()
```

{

```
    ...

    [self schedule:@selector(second:) interval:1.0/30];
```

}

the second schedule processed correctly.But the first one can not be called once.

And when I set interval of first schedule from 1.0f to 0.The first one could be called.

How can I do for the first schedule?

Answer (score 0):

Dude,check your method name that was called by first scheduler.It should be like

-(void)first:(id)sender

{

....

}